# Proof of propensity score theorem - problem with conditional expectation

Tags: causality, conditional-expectation, propensity-scores, confounding

My question is about the "propensity score theorem", which is quickly presented here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_score_matching#Main_theorems

The paper of the authors of the theorem, Rosenbaum and Rubin (1983), is available here : 
[the central role of the propensity score in observational studies for causal effects](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/70/1/41/240879) (the pdf document is freely available).

My question is about the fifth theorem, that can be found on the fifth page of the pdf file.

The proof is also reproduced here, in its most simple form : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwzkQnpXLDM

At some point we end up with E{P($z = 1 | x$) | $r_1$, $r_0$, P($z = 1 | x$)} and so they conclude that is is equal to P($z = 1 | x$) whereas I would say that it is equal to E{P($z = 1 | x$)} and since E{.} is the expectation over the $x$ (we know that from the beginning of the proof, when the person in the video is invoking the law of iterated expectations), we should end up with the unconditional probability $P(z = 1$).

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is simply something like $\mathbb E[X|Y,Z,X]$ which is equal to $X$, not $\mathbb E[X]$ because $X$ is given. In other words, given $P(z=1|x)$, your expectation about $P(z=1|x)$ should be the value given.